# Capture dynamic data from a field at fixed time intervals

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have prepared an excel which fetches data from an external website. The table is formed in such a way that the data gets refreshed every five minutes. Is there a way to capture a particular field value before every time it changes? or at different (fixed) time intervals?

Details -
The excel contains volume,turnover and price values of stocks derived from a website. It changes value during live market everytime it gets refreshed in the website (i have set a refresh timer of 5 minutes in the connection i have setup in excel). Is there a way of capturing this data before it gets refreshed?

Comment: How can you know when "before it gets refreshed"? What does "the data gets refreshed every five minutes" triggers? You should use there a cole line able to take whatever you need exactly "before refresh". I think...

Comment: There must be some VBA code that retrieves the info from the external website. In that code, there is a location  *just before* the data is replaced in the sheet. At that point, you could call a VBA procedure that reads the old cell value.. and put it somewhere else..

Comment: The excel is connected to an external website which contains stock prices, volume and other data. The website refreshes it data at regular intervals. My excel is connected to the website using data- connections- from web - url and other key info. So when website updates so does excel, by using refresh automatically option.